# How can you update nested information in AWS Amplify for react native?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-amplify

I have nested schema in graphql and I am trying to use the update function created by amplify to update a nested part of the schema, for a specific Information ID.  I have the ID of the table I want to update and want to update hasBooks section. Trying to use my current code I get two errors depending on what I try:

"The variables input contains a field name 'hasBooks' that is not defined for input object type 'UpdateInformationInput' "

and

"Variable 'input' has coerced Null value for NonNull type 'UpdateInformationInput!'"

schema:

```
type Information @model @searchable{
id: ID!
firstName: String!
lastName: String!
phoneNumber: Int
password: Int
timestamp:String!
hasBooks: [Books] @connection (name:"InformationBooks")


}
type Books @model { 
id: ID!
firstName: String!
lastName: String!
title: String!
information: Information @connection 
         (name:"InformationBooks")
}

export const updateInformation = /* GraphQL */ `
mutation UpdateInformation(
$input: UpdateInformationInput!
$condition: ModelInformationConditionInput
) {
updateInformation(input: $input, condition: $condition) {
  id
  firstName
  lastName
  phoneNumber
  password
  timestamp
  hasBooks {
    items {
      id
      firstName
      lastName
      title
    }
    nextToken
  }
 }
}
```

code:

```
const initialState = { 
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    title:''
}
const [formState, setFormState] = useState(initialState)

const [contactInfos, setContactInfos] = useState([])

async function addContactInfo() {
    try {
      const contactInfo = { ...formState }
      setContactInfos([...contactInfos, contactInfo])

      await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(updateInformation, 
 {input: { hasBooks: contactInfo, id:caseID}}))
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('error creating todo:', err)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

needed a one to many @connection with a @key

```
type Information @model @searchable {
id: ID!
firstName: String!
lastName: String!
phoneNumber: Int
password: Int
timestamp:String!
books: [Books] @connection (keyName:"byInformation", fields:["id"])


}

type Books @model 
@key (name:"byInformation", fields:["informationID"]) {
id: ID!
informationID:ID!
firstName: String!
lastName: String!
title: String!
}
```

and then create info by:

```
    const initialState = { 
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    title:'',
    informationID: caseID
    }


 const [contactInfos, setContactInfos] = useState([])

 async function addContactInfo() {
    try {
      const contactInfo = { ...formState }
      setContactInfos([...contactInfos, contactInfo])

      await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(createBooks, {input: 
 contactInfo}))
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('error creating todo:', err)
    }
  }
```